# replace all underscores (if any) with vowels present in the string

Tags: java, string

> You are given a string s consisting of lowercase English letters
>   and/or '_' (underscore).  You have to replace all underscores (if any)
>   with vowels present in the string.
>
> The rule you follow is: Each underscore can be replaced with any one
>   of the vowel(s) that came before it.
>
> You have to tell the total number of distinct strings we can generate
>   following the above rule.

My code is giving wrong output on some input

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;




import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String test = sc.nextLine();
        int a=0,e=0,i1=0,o=0,u=0;
        int ans = 1;

        for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(test);j++){

            String s = sc.nextLine();
           // System.out.println(s);

                for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

                    if( s.charAt(i)=='a' || s.charAt(i)=='o' || s.charAt(i)=='i' || s.charAt(i)=='e' || s.charAt(i)=='u' ) {

                            if(s.charAt(i)=='a')
                            a=1;

                            else if(s.charAt(i)=='e')
                            e=1;
                            else if(s.charAt(i)=='i')
                            i1=1;
                            else if(s.charAt(i)=='o')
                            o=1;
                            else if(s.charAt(i)=='u')
                            u=1;


                    }

                    else if(s.charAt(i)=='_'){
                        int sum = a + e +i1 +o + u;
                        if(sum != 0)
                        ans  = ans * sum;
                    }

                }


        if(ans!=0)
        System.out.println(ans);
        else
        System.out.println(1);
        ans = 1;
        a=0;
        e=0;
        i1=0;
        o=0;
        u=0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide Sample Input and expected Output

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the string and maintain the count of vowels

As soon as you encounter an underscore, multiply count of vowels with the sum.

```
int sum = 1, noOfVowels = 0;
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    if("aeiou".indexOf(str.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
        noOfVowels++;
    } else if("_".indexOf(str.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
        sum = (sum * noOfVowels <= 0) ? 1: sum * noOfVowels;
    }
}
return sum;
```

> Input: a_e_i
>
> Output: 2  (aAeAi, aAeEi)
>
> Input: ae_io_
>
> Output: 8 
>   (aeAioA,aeAioE,aeEioA,aeEioE,aeAioI,aeAioO,aeEioI,aeEioO)